# render without html and body tag

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, blocks, controllers, render

I created a controller which show a simple block.

```
public function execute() {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
```

When I go to my controller page route I get the block but I get too the ,  and  tags. So how to render a page without theses ?

I tried this :

```
namespace Maxime\Helloworld\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {
    public function execute() {
        echo $this->_view->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Maxime\Helloworld\Block\Hello')
        ->setTemplate('Maxime_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml')
        ->toHtml();
    }
}
```

but I get this html :

```
<html><head><style type="text/css"></style></head><body><h2>HelloWorld</h2>

<p>Congratulations ! You have created your first Magento Module !</p>
<p>The block classname is : Maxime\Helloworld\Block\Hello</p>
<p>Install kint with "composer require raveren/kint"</p>
<p>get the request fired by collection echo $myCollection-&gt;getSelect()-&gt;__toString();</p>
</body></html>
```

My block content is (I add in future some stuff here) :

```
<?php
namespace Maxime\Helloworld\Block;
class Hello extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

}
```

My template is (it's an old module test for testing the output without html) :

```
<h2>HelloWorld</h2>

<p>Congratulations ! You have created your first Magento Module !</p>
<p>The block classname is : <?php echo get_class($block) ?></p>
<p>Install kint with "composer require raveren/kint"</p>
<p>get the request fired by collection echo $myCollection->getSelect()->__toString();</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your need, you can create the block directly in the controller and display it without any other html.

> Update answer after update question.

You can also use the resultFactory of type RAW:

```
public function __construct(
//...
Magento\Framework\Controller\Result $rawResultFactory ,
//...        
)
{
    $this->rawResultFactory = $rawResultFactory;
}
```

and use that factory to create a raw result

```
public function execute(
)
{
    $html = $this->_view->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Maxime\Helloworld\Block\Hello')
    ->setTemplate('Maxime_Helloworld::helloworld.phtml')
    ->toHtml();

    $result = $this->rawResultFactory->create();
    $result->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    $result->setContents($html);
    return $result;
}
```

You can add the contents of your block in the setContents.

[Reference](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/141260832260/magento-2-controller-result-objects)

Comment: I updated my post I have also html and body tags

Comment: The browser itself adds the tags html, head, body ...
If you have a test.html file with just <h2>test</h2> and open in the browser, you will have the html, head, body rendered tags.